# youtube-api 3.0 update video

Tags: php, api, oauth-2.0, youtube

I've been trying to use this example https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/php/update_video.php to figure out how to update descriptions/tags/etc on my youtube videos.  I've got it to the point where I can click the link to authorize my app and then it redirects back after I authorize it..... but it says 'The session state did not match'.  I have made very few modifications to the sample code.  I just added my client_ID and client_secret_key.  I did also change the redirect from http to https because google made me enter the redirect with https on the credentials page.  I changed the video id to one that was uploaded by my credentials and that is it.  But I get 'the session state did not match'.  Any ideas why this would happen?

Thanks!

Comment: A random `state` value gets written into the session and appended to the login dialog URL; and when it returns back to your app from there, the state gets passed back, and is compared to the value stored in your session. This is protection against XSRF / replay attacks. Since you are getting this error, it most likely means your PHP session is somehow not working properly, so you need to go and investigate that.

Comment: OK, I made a bonehead mistake that was causing this, I actually deleted session_start(); from the code.  So I made it past the original issue now, but still the code is not working, its returning an error from the API...

code: 400
Invalid value at 'resource.snippet' (tags), Starting an object on a scalar field
status: INVALID_ARGUMENT

Its obviously when it try's to update the tags that its having the issue, but I have no idea why.  The code is the same as the example...